# What regression model or test is better for modeling commuting data?

Tags: regression, count-data

I have count of people commuting from an origin to a destination as my response/dependent variable. The independent variables are travel time (in minutes) and travel distance (in kilometers). I have access to R, SPSS, Minitab and Excel. Here are my questions:

1. What sort of regression would work for my outcome?
2. What test could I use to evaluate which regression model fits better
   (such as AIC, Wald test)?
3. Also what statistical test can I use to compare the different travel
   time and distance parameters against themselves?

Comment: What do you mean by "compare the different travel time and distance parameters against themselves?"

Comment: Hello, I mean to compare the statistical significance of the difference in values of the different distance measures which are all estimated for the same route(s) by different providers (like Google distance api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good web resource for beginners to statistics is the [IDRE at UCLA website](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat). You can check out [examples of count data analysis in R](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/dae/). To answer your questions:

1. You would choose the type of count data model to choose based on the
   distribution of your outcome, i.e. is it over-dispersed?
   under-dispersed? zero inflated? You would choose a different variant
   of the basic count model in each of these situations. Your 4 basic
   count data model flavors are: Poisson, negative binomial,
   zero-inflated Poisson (ZIP), and zero-inflated negative binomial
   (ZINB).  Without knowing much more about your outcome or what you
   have done so far, it's difficult to make a recommendation.  The links I have included above will tell you what kind of situation you have with your outcome data and the types of analysis available for those data.
2. For models that use maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) to estimate
   parameters, you would use a likelihood ratio test to compare two
   models.  These are some of the more common decisions that people make with regard to model choice:

   - Poisson vs. negative binomial ($H_0:$ $\beta_{OverdispersionParameter}$ =
     0 $\rightarrow$ If fail to reject $H_0$, then use Poisson)
   - Poisson vs. ZIP ($H_0:$ Both Poisson and ZIP fit the data equally well $\rightarrow$ If fail to reject $H_0$, then use Poisson)
   - Negative binomial vs. ZINB ($H_0:$ Both NB and ZINB fit the data equally well $\rightarrow$ If fail to reject $H_0$, then use NB)

The test to choose between Poisson vs. ZIP and NB vs. ZINB is called the Vuong test, and is used to determine whether excess zeroes in the data were a result of two separate processes as "regular" Poisson and "regular" NB both assume that the outcomes were the result of a single process.  Some statistical packages, Stata is one of them, do not automatically show you the result of the Vuong test, so check with your package's documentation on how to get this test statistic.

Comment: Thank you so much marquis, the link is very helpful. I'm still figuring out what model fits. Could you explain further what you meant when you used 'outcome' above? To clarify, I'm studying the effects/significance of the difference in travel time and distance estimates between several cities as provided by different platforms, like Google. I'm assessing how much an impact the difference in values from each provider makes when such data are used in modelling.

Comment: I'm trying to run a regression model to see which of the distance measures (predictors) best explains the commuting flow which is count of work commuters (response) on that route. I know that several other factors affect commuting apart from distance but I'm not looking to model those as my key interest is distance. It is possible that regression is not the answer and I'd really appreciate if you can steer me in the right statistical direction. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "Outcome" is whatever is on the left hand side of the equation you are modeling. This is what you call "response" in your comments above. Before modeling, you need to look at the distribution of your response variable to see if there are excess zeroes. If there are no excess zeroes, then you will compare the fit of the Poisson and NB models. In order to get unbiased estimates of the effect of distance on commuting flow, you need to control for other factors that affect commuting flow, so you need to include those other variables in your model. If my answer was useful, please mark it as such.

Comment: The Vuong test is no longer considered appropriate for comparing ZINB vs NB and ZP vs P